# Intrinsic construction of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ from $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory

We can construct the topological group of $p$-adic integers from the group of integers by taking an inverse limit:
$$\mathbb Z_p = \varprojlim_{n > 0} (\mathbb Z / p^n \mathbb Z)$$
This construction "sees" only the group structure of $\mathbb Z$.

> Is it possible to construct $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ from $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ "using" only the group structure of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: A possible way to reformulate the question would be : given a group $G$ which is isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$, but with no given isomorphism, is it possible to construct a group $H$ which is isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$, such that any chosen isomorphism with $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ "extends" to an isomorphism $H\cong SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ ?

Comment: The reduction $\bmod p^n$ has no simple expression in term of the generators of $SL_2(Z)$ (the almost free group structure of $SL_2(Z)$), we need to send the generators to $SL_2(Z/p^n Z)$

Answer (score 1):

The reduction $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})\to \mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})$ is surjective with kernel $\Gamma(p^n)$ thus $$SL_2(\Bbb{Z}_p)\cong \varprojlim SL_2(\Bbb{Z}/p^n\Bbb{Z})\cong\varprojlim SL_2(\Bbb{Z})/ \Gamma(p^n)$$
where $\cong$ are given by the *obvious* maps.

> Thus it reduces to the ways to define $\Gamma(p^n)$.

Comment: Can you get the kernel $\Gamma(p^n)$ only from the group structure of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ ? That's not clear to me.

Comment: I think no in the sense that you won't get anything simpler than sending the generators $\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1},\pmatrix{0&1\\ -1&0}$ to their image in $SL_2(Z/p^n Z)$

Comment: Yes, but that's "cheating" (unless you have a way to identify group theoretically these generators ?) cause you're using specific generators. I wonder if there isn't an intrinsic characterization of $\Gamma(p^n)$ (the question somehow amounts to this)

Comment: $\Gamma(p^n)$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing [...] (it is up to you to tell what is [...])

Comment: @reuns Saying [...] $= \Gamma(p^n)$ seems reasonable! (\s)

Comment: $ab\in \Gamma(p^n)$ iff $ba\in \Gamma(p^n)$  but I don't think it helps much. What Max is asking is the relations on $S,T$ as generators of $SL_2(Z/p^nZ)$

Comment: If we were talking about $\SL_n$ for *any* $n$ except for 2, the answer would be yes! A finite-index subgroup of $\SL_n(\mathbf Z)$ always contains $\Gamma(N)$ for some $N$ - this is the resolution of the "congruence subgroup problem" by Bass-Milnor-Serre: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup. So you could define $\Gamma(p^n)$ as e.g. the unique subgroup with a particular index (or whatever other property you'd like to use to distinguish the different $\Gamma(N)$'s from each other). Unfortunately, $\SL_2(\mathbf Z)$ has other finite-index subgroups...

Comment: So for $n\ge 3$, $SL_n(\hat{\Bbb{Z}})$ is the profinite completion of $SL_n(\Bbb{Z})$, but for $n=2$ it is larger than it.

Comment: reuns' last comment is interesting, because I asked this question when I was wondering about analogues of $SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ for nonarithmetic lattices (which do not exist for the higher rank $SL_n$)